# Flex: dynamic filtering (like google's or google finance)

Tags: apache-flex

I wanted to put a search box in my flex app that would act just like google or google finance: you start typing and a drop down list just below starts filtering the results dynamically. Does anyone know how to do this in flex? I am using flex and php so as the user types it will pull results off the server dynamically.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually called "AutoComplete", and there appear to be a number of them. [Here's one](http://code.google.com/p/flex-autocomplete/).

Comment: yeah, that's it. Sometimes half the problem is knowing what search term to use. thx.